# Excel User Form - how to get data from spreadsheet to show in user form again

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, I am a novice at VBA.  I created a user form in Excel that correctly loads the data into the spreadsheet and has command buttons that work.  However, how can I get a line of data added to the spreadsheet to redisplay in the form.  I know Excel has the form view that does this but the boxes are so small you can not see all of the data.

```
Private Sub AbstractReceipt_Initalize()

End Sub
Private Sub AbstractReceipt_Click()

    'ID = Sheet1.Range("A")
    'Abstract_Receipt_No = Sheet1.Range("B")
    'Date = Sheet1.Range("C")
    'Attorney_Name = Sheet.Range("D")
    'Client_Name = Sheet.Range("E")
    'Abstract_Co_Name = Sheet.Range("F")
    'Legal_Description = Sheet.Range("G")
    'Title_Opinion_No = Sheet.Range("H")
    'Signature_Information = Sheet.Range("I")
    'Other_Names = Sheet.Range ("J")


AbstractReceipt.IDBox.Text = ID
AbstractReceipt.AbReceiptBox.Text = Abstract_Receipt_No
AbstractReceipt.DateTextBox.Text = Date
AbstractReceipt.AttorneyTextBox.Text = Attorney_Name
AbstractReceipt.ClientTextBox.Text = Client_Name
AbstractReceipt.AbCoTextBox.Text = Abstract_Co_Name
AbstractReceipt.LegalTextBox.Text = Legal_Description
AbstractReceipt.TOTextBox.Text = Title_Opinion_No
AbstractReceipt.SigTextBox.Text = Signature_Information
AbstractReceipt.OtherTextBox.Text = Other_Names


End Sub

Private Sub AbCoTextBox_Enter()
AbCoTextBox.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub AbReceiptTextBox_Enter()
AbReceiptTextBox.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub AttorneyTextBox_Enter()
AttorneyTextBox.Text = ""
End Sub


Private Sub ClientTextBox_Enter()
ClientTextBox.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
AbstractReceipt.PrintForm

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
' Clear the form
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
ctl.Value = ""
ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
ctl.Value = False
End If
Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lAutoNo As Long

    With Sheet1
        lAutoNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet1.Columns(1))
        lAutoNo = lAutoNo + 1

        bEditing = True

        lRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = lAutoNo
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.AbReceiptTextBox.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.AttorneyTextBox.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.ClientTextBox.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.AbCoTextBox.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.LegalTextBox.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.AbCoTextBox.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.TOTextBox.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.SigTextBox.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.OtherTextBox.Value
        bEditing = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub DateTextBox_Enter()
DateTextBox.Text = ""

End Sub


Private Sub Frame1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub LegalTextBox_Enter()
LegalTextBox.Text = ""

End Sub


Private Sub OtherTextBox_Enter()
OtherTextBox.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub SigTextBox_Enter()
SigTextBox.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub TOTextBox_Enter()
TOTextBox.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub CancelCommandButton_Click()
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

Prerequisites: Empty worksheet with a user form named "UserForm1" which has one textbox named "TextBox1" and one button named "Command Button1".

Scenario: If a selection changes on the worksheet, UserForm1 shows with ActiveCell value in TextBox1. on CommandButton1 click, UserForm1 hides and unloads.

Code can be reused to meet specific requirements:

Worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
      UserForm1.Show
      UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

UserForm1 code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      UserForm1.Hide
      Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Comment: That works good for one active cell but if I have multiple fields on the form how do I get it to display the data for that line in all the fields?  If I put activecell.value for each field it displays the same data in each field.

Comment: ActiveCell is an example. You should replace it with Sheet1.Range("A1") or whatever the reference is. For multiple items on a single row you could use: UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value; UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = Sheet1.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much.  As I said I am not a programmer just trying to figure out some needs by using Excel and making it easy.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the  "yourbutton_click" you can update the textbox like

```
textbox.text = range("yourrange").value
```

Hope it helps, and you can also elaborate more your question.